# Approximating Lipschitz funtion by $C^1$ function.

Tags: real-analysis, functions, convergence-divergence, holder-spaces

Let $G:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ be a Lipschitz function and $L$ its Lipschitz constant. Suppose that $G(0)=0$. It is known that $G$ is almost everywhere differentiable and $G'\in L^\infty$ with $\|G'\|_{\infty}\leq L$.

My question is: Can I find a sequence $G_n:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ such that, $G_n(0)=0$, $G_n\in C^1(\mathbb{R})$, each $G_n$ is Lipschitz with constant $L_n$, $G_n(x)\to G(x)$, $G'_n(x)\to G'(x)$ almost everywhere and $L_n\to L$?

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes.  The continuous functions are dense in $L^1([a,b])$ on any interval.  So for each $n$, choose a continuous $F_n$ such that $\int_{-n}^n |F_n(x)-G'(x)|\,dx \to 0$.  Replacing $F_n$ by $F_n \vee -L \wedge L$ only makes the $L^1$ distance smaller.  Passing to a subsequence, we can also get $F_n \to G'$ almost everywhere.  Set $G_n(x) = \int_0^x F_n(y)\,dy$; then for $x \in [-n,n]$ we have $$|G(x) - G_n(x)| = \left\vert \int_0^x G'(y) - F_n(y)\,dy\right\vert \le \int_0^n |G'(y) - F_n(y)|\,dy \to 0.$$  In particular, we have $G_n \to G$ uniformly on compact sets.

I guess I didn't show that the Lipschitz constants converge; this is left as an exercise because I'm too lazy.

Comment: @Tomás Depends on how you understand $L_n$: the *minimal* Lipschitz constant, or any constant that works? If it's minimal, then $L_n\le L$, but inequality may be strict. If any constant that works, then $L$ works for $G_n$.

Comment: You are right @user75064, I was considering any constant. So the constant is less than or equal.